# Serving static files using Spark-java and Tomcat

Tags: java, spark-java

Previously I was using Jetty as a web-server for my Spark application. Now I want to deploy my app to Tomcat and everything is working fine except static files serving. 
The way I'm trying to setup static files serving is as follows

```
public class MySparkApplication implements SparkApplication {
    public void init() {
        staticFiles.location("/public");
        spark.Spark.get("/", (req, res) -> "test is OK");
    }
}
```

And my WAR-archive folder structure is

```
/META-INF
/WEB-INF
   /classes
   /lib
   /public
       test.html
```

But it doesn't work and I'm getting 404 when I'm trying to get test.html. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

/public should not be in WEB-INF. It should be in the directory, which also contains WEB-INF (The webapps root directory).